# MySQL select username only if username doesn't exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch usernames for my system, but if they exist in the table punishement_banned, it won't fetch that username.

I have made a query which should do that work, but for some reason, the query returns 0 values.

I have 1 row in punishement_banned with 1 name, total 2 names in the players table, so it must display 1 row.

```
SELECT players.username FROM players LEFT JOIN punishement_banned a ON a.username = players.username WHERE players.username != a.username;
```

But if I run this query, it will show the 2 names:

```
SELECT players.username FROM players LEFT JOIN punishement_banned a ON a.username = players.username;
```

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd650/4/0

```
SELECT username 
FROM players 
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
(  
   SELECT username 
   FROM punishement_banned 
   WHERE players.username = punishement_banned.username 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT username 
FROM players 
WHERE players.username NOT IN 
(SELECT username FROM punishement_banned)
```

The problem is, you join the tables on the usernames being equal, and then exclude the usernames equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

you have two contradicted conditions here

```
   ON a.username = players.username WHERE players.username != a.usernam
```

you need to use NOT IN

```
  SELECT username FROM players 
  WHERE players.username NOT IN (select username from punishement_banned )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement will find any username that can be matched against a row that doesnt have that username, which effectively is any username.

Use this:

`SELECT players.username FROM players WHERE players.username NOT IN(
SELECT username FROM punishement_banned
)`

Answer (score 0):

**Two alternatives:**

1. Using `IN` operator:

   ```
   SELECT username 
   FROM players 
   WHERE players.username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM punishement_banned)
   ```
2. Using `LEFT JOIN`:

   This would be faster than 1st method if you have thousands of records in the table.

   ```
   SELECT players.username FROM players 
   LEFT JOIN punishement_banned a ON a.username = players.username
   WHERE a.username=NULL
   ```

Comment: Unknown column 'punishement_banned.username' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user3123545: My second query will get faster results than inner select queries.